# t test on original result, log2(result), fold change and log2(fold change)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have some confusion about t test on original result, log2(result), fold change and log2(fold change). Hope to get some expert opinion on this.

Our original results are, for example, some biomarker values measured from 10 patients in clinical study. The biomarker was measured at 3 time points. t0, t1, t2.

Here we are using t test (in our case, paired t test) to compare biomarker values at t1 and t2.  Fold change at t1 and t2 is represented using t0 as baseline value,  result(t1)/result(t0) and result(t2)/result(t0).

I'm relatively certain about t test on original result and log2-transformed result.

**t test on original result**: compare the mean of results between two time points.

**t test on log2(result)**: compare the mean of log2(result), which is equivalent to one sample t test of fold change vs 1 (mean of fold change equals 1?), which is also equivalent to comparing geometric mean on original result.

However, I'm not sure about doing t test on fold change?

**t test on fold change**:

comparing mean of fold change(relative to t0) between t1 and t2?  Does that make sense? what's the meaning of test result?

**t test on log2(fold change)**:   I'm not sure about this...

**For further clarification**:

In many cases such as differential gene expression, people use log2 of fold change to represent differences with its associated p value. Does that mean we calculate log2(fold change), BUT do t test on log2(result) to get p value OR do t test directly on fold change or log2(fold change) to get p value?

**One additional question**:

If we use non-parametric test like wilcox to get the p value of fold change, what should we do wilcox on? fold change, log2(fold change) ? .......

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Suppose the means of biomarker values for placebo, trt A, trt B are 10, 20, 34. I think these three numbers are enough. My question is why you need the derived numbers from these three numbers?

Comment: I made some correction. It should be t0, t1 and t2.  I tried to t test between t1 and t2. In bioinformatics, people are interested in fold change. @user158565